# Compiling omcmd with isc-dhcp 4.3.3

Tags: networking, compiling, dhcp

As of this date, the distro package version of isc-dhcp is 4.3.3

I am trying to compile omcmd, a tool for accessing the dhcpd daemon using OMAPI. omcmd doesn't appear to have been supported since dhcp version 4.2.8.

See: https://github.com/parsley42/omcmd.git

The above referenced git tree won't compile. It doesn't seem to be finding files where it expects them to be, probably due to changes in the past two years.

Example:

```
omcmd.h:7:27: fatal error: omapip/result.h: No such file or directory
```

I'm hoping someone has dealt with this problem before.

Answer (score 0):

If that is a problem you are having compiling a program I would say that `fatal error: omapip/result.h: No such file or directory` almost definitely has to do with a missing dependency (library). To shorten your search time, this means in the package will have a `-dev` prefix at the end of it, which means it is used for building packages. Try downloading `libghc-threads-dev` for example and see if that does the trick. In this case I simply looked up "result" in Synaptic package manager and skimmed it for `-dev` packages.